# How to select only several columns from GroupBy... First()

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to select "highest" licence user has per year.

I started with:

```
var lic = _context.Licences
            .Where(l => l.MemberNumber == memberNumber) 
            .GroupBy(l => new { l.LicenceYear }
            (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(l => l.ProfessionalTitleId)
            .First());
```

and it works.

However it always returns ALL columns from Licence which I don't want. Moreover I would like to select some child property like `l.Title.TitleNumber`, but no matter where I put `.Select(l => new {l.LicenceNumber, l.Title.TitleNumber})` generated sql query selects all columns from Licences, and only from Licences.

I have also tried

```
var lic = _context.Licences
            .Where(l => l.MemberNumber == User.GetMemberNumber())            
            .GroupBy(l => new { l.LicenceYear },
            l => new { l.Title.TitleNumber, l.LicenceYear, l.LicenceNumber, l.Title.ProfessionalTitleId },
            (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(l => l.ProfessionalTitleId)
            .First());
```

Interestingly enough it properly creates ROW_NUMBER() using `ProfessionalTitleId` from `Title` but still selects all columns from Licences.

So, how to modify query to select only some columns?

Comment: Those who take time to read the question would see that I have tried using projections in different ways and in different places but for this query it is not giving desired select query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is new for EF Core 6, and I saw it's implementation - they just clone parsing context and probably with all fields. Probably they will improve projection later if you create issue in GitHub.

Anyway, there is workaround which emulates the same query without grouping:

```cs
var filtered = _context.Licences.Where(l => l.MemberNumber == memberNumber);

var lic = 
    from d in filtered.Select(l => new { l.LicenceYear }).Distinct()
    from l in filtered.Where(l => l.LicenceYear == d.LicenceYear)
        .OrderByDescending(l => l.ProfessionalTitleId)
        .Take(1)
    select new 
    { 
        l.Title.TitleNumber, 
        l.LicenceYear, 
        l.LicenceNumber, 
        l.Title.ProfessionalTitleId 
    };
```

Comment: This is it, thanks. What kind of join is created by two `from...` without explicit join keyword?

Comment: It depends, if second `from` contains only `Where` it will be `INNER JOIN`, if from contains `Where.DefaultIfEmpty` -  `LEFT JOIN`, if from sequence is more complex - `CROSS/OUTER APPLY JOIN`.